Condition-result inversion in "If I wanted to go to Paris, I would have to work hard"
According to a book from Oxford, the if clause in the second conditional expresses the imaginary condition and the main clause the imaginary result but, in the sentence If I wanted to go to Paris, I would have to work very hard, I would say that having to work hard is the imaginary condition and being able to go to Paris is the imaginary result, so there is a semantic clause inversion in this case, Do you agree?

IMO it's the other way round: going to Paris is the imaginary condition, and working hard is the necessary means to achieve it, which is not imaginary but a logical consequence to fulfil the desire.

@WeatherVane would you call that a logical result?

"result" is a poor way to understand what would be necessary to accomplish a (hypothetical) goal.  "If I wanted to get up on the roof, I would need a ladder."

"If I wanted to go to Paris...."  from which we can infer that the speaker doesn't want to go to Paris. The condition is imaginary, because it is counterfactual. The speaker creates a condition that they know isn't true, then considers the consequences.
"... I would have to work hard".  This is the consequence that the speaker draws from the hypothesis.  Logically it might be true or not (since the hypothesis is untrue, we can't say anything about whether this is true) But the speaker claims that it is a certain consequence of wanting to go to Paris.
Such sentences are common in discussions of formal logic, but they are rather rare in natural English.

Note that there are several a hidden assumptions in the sentence.  If taken taken literally it is nonsense.  I desire to go Paris does not cause an obligation to work hard.  You can continue to want to go to Paris and continue to be Lazy and never go.
